# Django: hwo to make queries between 2 tables that are not related in the model?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have 2 models that are not related (maybe it should...)

I need to make a query that select all records of my table **Stock** WITH related rows in **Parametrage** based on asp_sto_loc=asp_par_loc

Something like SQL:

> select * from pha_asp_sto left join pha_asp_par on pha_asp_par.asp_par_loc=asp_sto_loc;

How can I make such a query in Django?

**models.py**

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    asp_sto_cle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asp_sto_loc = models.CharField("Site concerned", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    asp_sto_pla = models.IntegerField("Quantity of placebos available", null=True, blank=True,)
    asp_sto_asp = models.IntegerField("Quantity of aspirin available", null=True, blank=True)

class Parametrage(models.Model):

    asp_par_cle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asp_par_loc = models.CharField("Site concerned by settings", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    asp_par_ale = models.IntegerField("Site alert value for the site", null=True, blank=True,)
    asp_par_con = models.IntegerField("Site confort value for the site", null=True, blank=True,)
```

Comment: Check this article: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) this will work in your case:

```
Stock.objects.extra(
    select={
        field_name: f'SELECT {field_name} FROM Parametrage WHERE Parametrage.asp_par_loc = Stock.asp_sto_loc' for field_name in Parametrage._meta.fields if field_name != 'id'
   }
)
```

Comment: thanks for replying... I do not manage to make this works but I will read th doc... neverthless, I have already read that extra() will be depreacted...